# React start set port number from CLI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm attempting to start my react server through linux CLI with a specified port number. I am NOT asking about changing the package.json script to include a defined port number.

I need to be able to start multiple react instances with different ports through CLI.

I have seen recommendations such as

`npm start --PORT=4000`,
`npm start --PORT 4000`,
`npm start -- --PORT=4000`

Of which none work, they all set the port to the default of 3000, or if I have a defined port in the package.json such as 5000, it defaults to that.

Whats the correct command for setting the port through CLI?

Comment: try `PORT=4000 npm start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually an environment variable for the port, so you can specify a `PORT` environment variable before`npm start`

```
export PORT=3005; npm start #For Linux
$env:PORT=3005; npm start #For Powershell
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by adding PORT=4000 before react-scripts start in package.json.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start"
}
```

then you can execute npm start